# Adding and listing has_many through associations in Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have the following setup:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :device_ownerships, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :devices, :through => :device_ownerships

end

class device < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :device_ownership, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :user, :through => :device_ownership

end


class deviceOwnership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user  
  belongs_to :device
  validates_uniqueness_of :device_id, :scope => :user_id
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => :device_id
end
```

I am trying to achieve the following in Active Admin:

**In Edit screen**

1) List all devices that belong to user with an option to delete the device or destroy the `deviceOwnership` that connects device  to user

2) have an option to create a new pairing user-device from existing devices (by creating new `DeviceOwnership`).

3) have an option to create new device and add it to user via new `DeviceOwnership`.

I listed my problems with what I have now in comments below:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do

  permit_params :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :role,
    device_ownerships_attributes: [:device_id, :user_id],
    devices_attributes: [:device_identifier]

  index do |user|
    user.column :email
    user.column :current_sign_in_at
    user.column :last_sign_in_at
    user.column :sign_in_count
    user.column :role
    actions
  end

  filter :email

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "User Details" do
      f.input :email
      f.input :password
      f.input :password_confirmation
      f.input :role, as: :radio, collection: {Editor: "editor", Moderator: "moderator", Administrator: "administrator"}

  #This one  allows to create new devices but also lists all existing devices with option to modify their device_identifier column which I don't want
      f.has_many :devices, :allow_destroy => true, :heading => 'Themes', :new_record => true do |cf|
        cf.input :device_identifier
      end

  #This one  lists all the devices but no option to remove any of them.
      f.input :devices

  #This one shows dropdownw with existing devices but allows to swap them

      f.has_many :devices, :allow_destroy => true do |device_f|
        device_f.input :device_identifier, :as => :select, :collection => device.all.map{ |device| [device.device_identifier] }, include_blank: false,
      end


      f.actions
    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
f.has_many :devices, :allow_destroy => true, :heading => 'Themes', :new_record => true do |cf|
  cf.input :device_identifier
end
```

looks like it might do the job. You could check whether the cf.object is a new record and only let the user change the `device_identifier` in that case.

`cf.input :device_identifier if cf.object.new_record?`

or something like `cf.input :device_identifier, input_html: { readonly: !cf.object.new_record? }`

What do you think?